# Stray Number on table

Tags: tables, latex-misc

I have a stray "7" on my table, but I can't find any reason why the code would display it. I have tried recompiling but it doesn't go. [image: Why would a 7 come in the middle of it?].

Here is the code for that part of the document.

```
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Salt}    & \textbf{Height of Growth (in cm)} \\ \hline
        $\ce{CaCl_2}$    & 4.6 \\ \hline
        $\ce{CuSO_4}$    & 1.3\\ \hline
        $\ce{NiSO_4}$    & 4.1\\ \hline
        $\ce{CoCl_2}$    & 0.9\\ \hline
        $\ce{MnCl_2}$    & 7.8\\ \hline
        $\ce{K_2Cr_2O_7}$ & 0\\  
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Heights of growth recorded by different salts}
\end{subfigure}
```

The other tables in the document seem to be working fine. Is this a bug in some package or in my code or in latex? I am compiling using pdflatex on http://www.sharelatex.com

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe it's the page number if the table is at the bottom of the page. We cannot say that much without the real compilable code (minimal version, MWE).

Comment: Could that be the page number? You should supply enough code for us to replicate this issue. At the moment that is not possible.

Comment: It does happen to be the page number. Thank you so much. Though even if I supplied more of the code nearby, I doubt u would be able to replicate this without the entire document. @TeXnician Can u pls write that as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Comment: Answered it (see below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually such numbers are page numbers. If your table happens to be at the bottom of the page and does not break, it will just overlay the page number what causes such strange numbers.